# Story identification: SF webcomic with two women travelling around the solar system, working?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Years ago, I read a webcomic that I'd like to find again. Sadly I don't remeber the title or how I found it. Here's the things I remember:

- The story was clearly SF
- The main characters where two (oldish, I think) women, I'm not sure if friends or lovers or on/off lovers
- They travel around an science fictional solar system and work odd jobs
- I think there was no really coherent storyline, rather single episodes
- The graphical style was vaguely realistic (no cartoonish aesthetics) and colourful
- The plots, the jobs they worked and the backgrounds were all rather weird

Can anyone point me to the right webcomic?

Comment: I'm sure I've read this, but I can't find it.  I have some vague memories.  Do any of these ring a bell? [1] There were a sequence of story-lines, one on each planet. [2] One or both may have been a robot? [3] Sex and booze [4]  There was one story-line about extreme debt.  They borrowed, like, $5 to buy a sandwich and within minutes were billions in debt.  They walked over a grating under which were thousands of debtors kept underground.

Comment: 1 and 3 definitly, 4 would fit but I don't recall.

Comment: that does not mean that can't be it, maybe I just didn'T follow the story that far.

Comment: @user1008646 The comic you're thinking of is Nine Planets Without Intelligent Life, but I don't think that's the answer because the protagonists are both robots, not women.

http://www.bohemiandrive.com/comics/npwil.html

Answer (score 4):

Could you be thinking of the webcomic [Dicebox](http://www.dicebox.net/) by Jenn Manley Lee?

Comment: thx, but that's not it.